# Help with gap mask filling and Landsat 7 in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, remote-sensing, landsat-7

I have downloaded images from Landsat 7 ETM+ SLC-off with corresponding gap mask. Which is the best method for using it with ArcGIS 10?

I tried the mask and statistical method described in [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000058000000) but I have some troubles, (after I apply the mask function, the statistical function need the input raster that is somewhere in a temporary file that can't access it.)

Comment: Are you using Landsat 7 images mainly for display purposes or for scientific purposes?  What is your area of interest and what was the source of your image downloads?

Comment: scientific, now im working with flood analysis, and rainwater harvesting. yet im not a advenced user. the source was the USGS - Landsat 7 ETM+ SLC-off imagery , why Spot images are to expensive. i think there is a significant diference working with gap filled that no filled, therefore im asking, and also would like to know how is solved.

Comment: If you're not looking for legacy data, Landsat-8 imagery is now available and has excellent coverage now that's it's completed so many orbits.

Comment: Also, for scientific purposes you are best to avoid Landsat-7 unless absolutely necessary as the data quality is very low and you can't correct it much beyond merely making it look reasonable.

Comment: the problem is that im using 2012 images (high flood inundation in my workzone), and landsat 8 began on 2013. im trying Aaron tips. also i try removing the gaps, and lets see if works for my project.

Comment: Where is your area of interest?  There may be more suitable (free) data.

Comment: Paraguay, Path/row 227/076. dates march, april, may (rain period) and august (dry season) 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some alternatives to ArcGIS, the USGS offers several solutions to deal with the Landsat 7 ETM+ gaps.

- [Filling the Gaps to use in Scientific Analysis](https://landsat.usgs.gov/sci_an.php)
- [Filling the Gaps for Display](https://landsat.usgs.gov/filling_the_gaps_for_display.php)

Additionally, **GRASS** provides functionality that may be of interest to you, including:

- [r.patch](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.patch.html)

> Creates a composite raster map layer by using known category values
>   from one (or more) map layer(s) to fill in areas of "no data" in
>   another map layer.

- [r.fillnulls](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.fillnulls.html)

> Fills no-data areas in raster maps using spline interpolation.

For a **QGIS**/GDAL solution, use [gdal_fillnodata](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_fillnodata.html) which is available in QGIS at: Raster >
Analysis > Fill nodata

> Fill raster regions by interpolation from edges

Comment: ok, i take a look. but for arcgis is no method know?

Comment: ok, i tried again with the mask function, and the statistical function, and i have this http://img42.com/1inKt+ .the first a sector with the gaps, the second with statistical function (Row 7 and column 1) then saved and again statistical function (Row 7 and column 1) that is the third image. its pretty close i think. but only a half of the map is good. with the Qgis i have some troubles with the options they have.